# Swift - How can I get a list of all photos and videos on iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I would like to be able to view a list of both photos and videos stored on the user's iPhone so I can allow them to select the file for upload. So far, I have it working where photos show up in the list, but no videos are showing up. The code I'm using to display the photos library is the following:

```
@IBAction func btnAddPicOrVideo(sender: AnyObject) {

    let pickerC = UIImagePickerController()        
    pickerC.delegate = self        
    self.presentViewController(pickerC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

As I mentioned, I'm able to display a list of photos and select one of them just fine. The problem is that I'm unable to see or select any videos. Is there a way to specify for both pictures and videos to be displayed? Or, do I have to display pictures and videos separately?

I'm currently running my code on the simulator and I have a video file stored on it locally.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this resolved by specifying

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

and I changed the code I specified above as such:

```
@IBAction func btnAddPicOrVideo(sender: AnyObject) {

    let pickerC = UIImagePickerController()        
    pickerC.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as NSString, kUTTypeMovie as NSString]
    pickerC.delegate = self        
    self.presentViewController(pickerC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: (1) better to say `as String` than `as NSString`. (2) That doesn't solve the problem; now you're going to see videos and not still images, because you've replaced the `mediaTypes` with another _single_ type.

Comment: You're exactly right. I'm in a hurry to get this completed. So, although it showed the front of the picture album when the library opened, after checking inside I noticed it only displayed the video. I've got to figure out how to specify both types at once, if possible.

Comment: I've got it working now. I'll edit my answer above to reflect the change that is now working. Thank you for the response.

Comment: There you go, that's the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ScoutDetailPage: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

var picker:UIImagePickerController? = UIImagePickerController()
let imageView = UIImageView ()
{

override func viewDidLoad(){

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.loadOrTakePhotos()

}

func loadOrTakePhotos()

{

if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
    {
picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        picker?.delegate = self

self .presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
        else if (pickersegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
        {
            picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            picker?.delegate = self

          self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
 let pickedimage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

imageView.image = pickedimage
            if (imageView.image != nil)
            {
                print("image not empty")

// Do something here.

picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

            }
            else
            {
                print("IMAGE VIEW NIL")
            }
        }

    func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {

        if error != nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save Failed",
                message: "Failed to save image",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,
                completion: nil)
        }
    }



}
```