# Application that plays videos from the video library

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, video

I would like to create a simple app that does some video playback (with a few extra controls) of videos that you would find in the videos app.  I've been searching and searching for a way to access the videos but I haven't found a single API that plays from the videos app.

Every solution I find plays videos from the photos app. I have apps that access the videos library on my iPad/iPhone so I'm assuming it's possible. Does anyone have the api for this?

Answer (score 0):

Apps cannot access data from other applications on iOS, you cannot access the data of other apps unless it's made available by the app via a web server etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use UIImagePicker to load the videos and images that are on your phone.

You can check out a reference [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723308/swift-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-photos-and-videos-on-iphone)

As for getting the videos off the videos app, that's not really possible (as far as I know), but you are able to show just photos or just videos with UIImagePicker using the `mediaTypes` property.